# Reset Value on JSON Autocomplete Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

I'm having a bit of trouble with the code below, note it's not mine but from an open source application.

First, the important part of the code:

```
var InputID = $Element.attr('id') + 'Autocomplete';
        $Element.removeClass('\'' + SearchClass + '\'');
        $Element.removeClass(SearchClass);
        $Element.attr('id', InputID);
        $Element.prev().attr('id', InputID + 'Selected');

        // escape possible colons (:) in element id because jQuery can not handle it in id attribute selectors
        if (SearchClass == 'QueueSearch'){
            Core.Agent.QueueSearch.Init( $('#' + Core.App.EscapeSelector(InputID) ) );
        }
        else if (SearchClass == 'ServiceSearch'){
            Core.Agent.ServiceSearch.Init( $('#' + Core.App.EscapeSelector(InputID) ) );
        }
        else if (SearchClass == 'SLASearch'){
            Core.Agent.SLASearch.Init( $('#' + Core.App.EscapeSelector(InputID) ) );
        }
        else if (SearchClass == 'AgentUserSearch'){
            Core.Agent.UserSearch.Init( $('#' + Core.App.EscapeSelector(InputID) ) );
        }
        else if (SearchClass == 'CustomerUserCompanySearch'){
            Core.Agent.CustomerUserCompanySearch.Init( $('#' + Core.App.EscapeSelector(InputID) ) );
        }
        else if (SearchClass == 'CustomerCompanySearch'){
            Core.Agent.CustomerCompanySearch.Init( $('#' + Core.App.EscapeSelector(InputID) ) );
        }
        else if (SearchClass == 'CIClassSearch'){
            Core.Agent.CIClassSearch.Init( $('#' + Core.App.EscapeSelector(InputID) ) );
        }
        else if (SearchClass == 'TicketSearch'){
            Core.Agent.ITSMCITicketSearch.Init( $('#' + Core.App.EscapeSelector(InputID) ) );
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
```

The first time I search for one of the fields below, the autocomplete function works perfectly and return the data I want, I also see the code appends the class:
[inspect element_AutoComplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4arr.jpg)

Now, If I try to run the same search again or use any other autocomplete field, that field does not reset nor it appends the autocomplete class:
[inspect element - no autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYVFr.jpg)

I get around this ONLY reloading the page.
So, how do I reset the field on submit to make it usable again without reloading the page?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: always use === in JS